# how to use ajax in laravel 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use ajax in laravel 4.  I followed the steps from this example: http://codehappy.daylerees.com/ajax-content

My code is listed below.

JavaScript :

```
        $.post(BASE+'checkUserName', {
            un: userName,
            }, function(data) {
                alert(data);
                //$('#content').html(data);
            });
```

Route :

```
 Route::post('checkUserName',function(){
    return true;
});
```

In a footer, I have this :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var BASE = "<?php echo URL::base(); ?>"; </script>
```

The problem seems to be with variable BASE.  When I view source, it shows :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var BASE = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Whoops! There was an error.</title>

    <style>.cf:before, .cf:after {content: " ";display: table;} .cf:after {clear: both;} .cf 

    {*zoom: 1;}
body {
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #2B2B2B;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  padding:0}


.
.
.
```

Can someone give me a simple example of using ajax in laravel 4?

Answer (score 2):

`URL::base()` was in L3 and in L4 it has been replaced with `URL::to('/') or Request::root()`
**[Changelog (Laravel 4)](http://wiki.laravel.io/Changelog_%28Laravel_4%29)**

And just for info no need to declare Base variable like that you can directly use blade syntax in script,if it is embedded in your view

Comment: Can you please explain how `you can directly use blade syntax in script`?

Comment: @PiTheNumber if the javascript is in the same view then you can use `{{URL::to('/')}}` directly any where you need

Comment: Thank you. I also found something about [rendering script files with the blade template engine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18078071/956397).