# Laravel 4 blade syntax within my javascript files

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

My home page had some inline javascript that was mixed up with some blade syntax e.g.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @if(Auth::user())
            if(path.indexOf('/user/' + {{Auth::user()->id}} ) != -1) {
                    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
            };
        @endif
    </script>
```

It worked until I wanted to move the javascript to an external file.js. I got error whenever blade syntax was added. Is there a way I can fuse blade syntax in my javascript files.js? I tried renaming to file.blade.js with no luck...

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL => @if

Comment: That actually works well for me. You should have made it an answer. I realised my home page was getting too cluttered with javascript. I believe this doesnt result in an extra request hence the page load speed is the same.  Why would you recommend against it?

Comment: Not any specific reason, I just didn't get the use.

Comment: I find blade syntax easy. But the main problem is that my page was overloaded with javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can try this save your javascript file in `app/views` folder and rename it to `xxx.blade.php` , yes `.blade.php` because **Blade Engine** will parse it only if its `.blade.php` and use `@include('your javascript filename')` to include the javascript file *parsed by Blade*, it will work.

Answer (score 42):

Although the accepted solution will work, this is a most definitely an antipattern.

If I saw this not being the one who wrote it, I would be extremely confused to what's going on.

My suggestion is in your PHP file, have a  block, which gets all of the values that you'll need in your external files, then call the external files.

So in your PHP file you would have something like:

```
<script>
    var userID = "{{ Auth::user()->id }}";
    var isUser = "{{ Auth::user() }}"
</script>

{{ HTML::script('path/to/js/file.js') }}
```

And in your javascript file:

```
if(isUser)
{
    if(path.indexOf('/user/' + userID ) != -1) {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    };
}
```

Comment: plus 1 for seperating responsibilities and allowing me to minify my js if needed

Comment: @BillGarrison, keep in mind that yes, you can minify -- but you can't obfuscate because that will change variable names!

Comment: How would you use this solution and also be able to obfuscate?  Can it be done?  Any tricks that might allow obfuscation while preserving the specific variables?

Comment: You can ensure that the variable names `userID` and `isUser` won't be obfusticated by tying them to the global scope (like `window.userID` and `window.isUser`)... which is what you need to do anyway to be able to access those variables in a separate JS file.

Obfuscators like UglifyJS should detect that a variable is accessing the global scope and won't obfusticate them by default. But if there's any uncertainty, then accessing it explicitly through `window` will make it clear.

Comment: I don't like this solution because it pollutes the global scope, what I usually do to pass variables to my JS is `<input id="isUser" type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user() }}" />` then just get it from JS using `$('#isUser').val()`

Comment: I also recommend @IvanCastellanos approach, if you can appropriately bind a variable to an HTML element, do it.  Most all of the time I handle it the way Ivan suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I was doing the same than @BrandonRomano, but I found a better approach. Sending directly the value from PHP to JS vars using:
[PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer)

PHP:

```
JavaScript::put([
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'user' => User::first(),
    'age' => 29
]);
```

JS:

```
console.log(foo); // bar
console.log(user); // User Obj
console.log(age); // 29
```

You can set a namespace like:

```
console.log(server.foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are outputing string from PHP, so you have to enclose that string in `'`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if(Auth::user())
        if(path.indexOf('/user/' + '{{Auth::user()->id}}' ) != -1) {
                $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        };
    @endif
</script>
```

Comment: I am getting an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL => @if

Comment: What is the name of the file? It should be named `whatever.blade.php`

Comment: It is a .blade.php file but the error disappeared when I enclosed the @if statements with in ' too. like '@if(Auth::user())'. Problem is, the blade php didnt run