# Pass Data from Controller to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I want to pass data from my Controller to a JavaScript that handles a Google Bar Chart.

## composer

```
$tmp = 6;
return view('pages.template', ['tmp' => $tmp]);
```

from my `template.blade.php` I call the Google Chart

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

.js file:

```
var tmp = 6;
var tmp2 = parseInt('{!! $tmp !!}');

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['comment1', 'comment2'],
    ["- 6 days", tmp],
    ["- 5 days", tmp2],
    ["- 4 days", 31],
    ["- 3 days", 12],
    ["- 2 days", 10],
    ["- 1 day", 3],
    ["today", 4]
```

the 2nd bar from Google-Bar-Chart is blank ....
[image]

But there should be displayed my variable.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe try the response from Brandon ["here"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074771/laravel-4-blade-syntax-within-my-javascript-files) only because I think you're trying to use the php variable on a linked .js file which won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace :

```
var tmp2 = parseInt('{!! $tmp !!}');
```

By :

```
var tmp2 = parseInt(<?php echo $tmp; ?>);
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use **Blade** syntax in your **JS** file. In order for that to work, this file would need to be processed by Blade compiler. It means that instead of including JS file in your website directly, you need to include a URL that will be processed by Laravel and output Javascript code. It is possible, but it's usually a bad option. Instead of fetching a light JS file directly from the server, **additional request will need to be processed by Laravel**.

What you need to do is:

1. Put your Javascript in a Blade template
2. Create a controller action that will

   ```
   class JavascriptController extends Controller {
     public function javascript() {
       $tmp = 6;
       return view('javascript', ['tmp' => $tmp]);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add a route to that action in your **routes.php**

   ```
   Route::get('/javascript', 'JavascriptController@javascript');
   ```
4. Instead of including the original Javascript file include a URL that will execute this controller action

   ```
   <script src="{{route(javascript)}}"></script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var tmp = {!! json_encode($tmp->toArray()) !!};
console.log(tmp);

</script>
```

In Your controller, you could do the following

```
public function index()

{

$tmp = Tmp::get();

return view('tmp.index', compact('tmp'));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The variable `$tmp` seems not be parsed successfully in `.js` file. why not you put the code in `.js` file into `template.blade.php`?

Comment: I don't think shoving javascript into a view file in order to coerce it into working is the best approach.